# Using nano in Cygwin's Mintty: Shortcuts don't work when editing git commit message

Tags: git, cygwin, nano, mintty

I'm using Cygwin with Mintty and have set the git editor to nano: `git config --global core.editor "nano"`.

Now when I just run `nano`, the UI is black and white and the shortcuts, like ctrl+o and ctrl-x work just as expected. But when I create a git commit, nano's UI is colored, the shortcuts don't work any more and when I press the arrow keys, the letters A,B,C and D are entered. On Linux, I've never seen nano behave differently when run through git.

What causes this and how can I disable this?

Edit: It seems this is caused by a .nanorc file in C:\cygwin64\usr\share\nano, but there's no git.nanorc or gitcommit.nanorc file in there.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I ran `git config --global core.editor "C:/cygwin64/bin/nano.exe"` instead of `git config --global core.editor "nano"`.